# .htaccess rewrite not working on port other than 80

Tags: .htaccess, centos5, httpd

I have a simple .htaccess that redirect everything that's not a file or directory to index.php

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This works perfectly on port 80 and 443 but gives 404 on https://mysite.com:450 in case url like https://mysite.com:450/controller/action is invoked.

What needs to be modified?

Comment: Are the vhosts that match ports 80 and 443 exactly the same as the one that matches port 450?

Comment: yup! only difference is base directory and 450 requires client authentication

Comment: thanks @Ladadadada I checked vhosts AllowOverride All was missing from 450 conf :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suspicion is that the vhosts that match ports 80 and 443 are not exactly the same as the one that matches port 450.

Most likely that the :450 vhost is missing `AllowOveride All` or has a different `DocumentRoot` that doesn't contain the same `.htaccess` file.